# VS2010 WPF debugging: TextBox typing is very slow, just me?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I am creating a new application in .NET 4 and the TextBoxes are way too slow, I haven't applied any Styles, Bindings etc. just plain TextBox.

I tried to create a new project with a TextBox in Visual Studio 2008 and the TextBox works good.

Note: The problem only occurs in debug, when I run without debugging (^F5) it works good in VS2010 as well.

See the [Microsoft Connect Bug Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/574393/vs2010-wpf-debugging-textbox-typing-is-very-slow-just-me#details) I submitted.

Comment: If it only happens in debug mode and doesn't happen in 2008 you could try disabling IntelliTrace in the options.

Comment: That solved my question. post as answer and i will mark

Comment: Actually I selected "IntelliTrace events only" and works, no need to entirely disable it.

Comment: I've the same problem but with Visual Studio 2010 Professional that do not have Intellitrace options.

Didi you have any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the Intellitrace.
Once I disabled it everything works just fine.

Credit to [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265600/kris) for his comment.